# "Misuse that has been going on that long" - or "a misuse"?

Tags: articles

From an article by McWhorter: *"[The Grumpy Grammarian: Surely, Actually the Scolds Have Lost Their Minds](http://www.newrepublic.com/article/113481/grumpy-grammarian-joe-biden-misusing-literally)"*

> Complaints about *literally* long predate Biden, of course. An early rendition came from the satirist and journalist Ambrose Bierce, who declared in 1909 that “to affirm the truth of the exaggeration is intolerable.” But “wrong” uses of *literally* go back to Dryden, Austen, and Thackeray.
>
> “**Misuse**” that has been going on that long would seem to suggest that literally’s meaning has, well, changed.

Since **misuse** is postmodified by "*that has been going on that long*", would it be okay to use an indefinite article before it?

> **A** “**misuse**” that has been going on that long would seem to suggest that *literally*’s meaning has, well, changed.

Why did the author of the article use no article before "misuse"?

Comment: You didn't ask about the quotation marks around "misuse" and other words. So I assumed you knew what their purpose is for.

Comment: @CarSmack - Did the quotation marks affect the choice of an article? I guess they were used to stress the author's view that the "misuse" is not really misuse.

Comment: No, they do not at all affect article usage. They simple denote the author's ironic attitude towards such words "wrong" and "misuse".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...But “wrong” **uses** of *literally* go back to Dryden, Austen, and Thackeray.

**uses** is a plural count noun.

> “**Misuse**” that has been going on that long would seem to suggest that literally’s meaning has, well, changed.

According to [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/misuse), "**Misuse**" can be a count noun and a mass noun. The word is related to *use*, of course, with the prefix [*mis-*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mis-) meaning *bad, badly, wrong, wrongly.*

**Misuse** here is a mass noun. We know it is a mass noun, because single count nouns usually require an article. In addition, we know from the relative clause that it is meant to refer back to the *multiple* 'wrong uses'. As such, the previous multiple 'wrong uses' can be seen as examples of 'misuse'. *This is felicitous.*

Else,

> A “**misuse**” (***but which one?***) that has been going on that long would seem to suggest that *literally*’s meaning has, well, changed.

What would this singular count noun be doing?

Consider:

Many wrong thoughts about the word go back to Dryden, Austen, and Thackeray. A "wrong-thought" (***but which one?***) that has been going on that long would seem to suggest...

It seems to be not felicitous.

Answer (score 2):

> Why did the author of the article use no article before "misuse"?

Why might we not use an article there? In order to present the noun as paradigm of the practice it names, rather than as an instance of it, as a rhetorical strategy designed to question the aptness of the label "misuse" for this situation.

*Misuse* without a determiner is an abstraction.

We could also say, as you have said, "*A* misuse that has gone on for so long..." in which case we would have begun our statement by implicitly acceding to the label, only to reverse ourselves in the second half of our sentence.

P.S. The linguistic effect of not using an article there is imitated by (or reflected by) the quotation marks placed around the word.